# tf.TensorArray across multiple computation steps supposed to remember?

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying this:

```
  ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, size=3)
  index = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
  value = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
  flow = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
  ta_new = tf.TensorArray(dtype=ta.dtype, handle=ta.handle, flow=flow)
  write = ta_new.write(index, value).flow
  read = ta_new.read(index)
  f = 0
  f = session.run(write, feed_dict={index: 0, value: 1, flow: f})
  f = session.run(write, feed_dict={index: 1, value: 2, flow: f})
  assert_equal(session.run(read, feed_dict={index: 0, flow: f}), 1)
  assert_equal(session.run(read, feed_dict={index: 1, flow: f}), 2)
```

That does not work. I get the error:

```
Could not read from TensorArray index 0 because it has not yet been written to.
```

Is there any way to make it work?

As I understand, the `TensorArray.flow` is used as an alternative to `tf.control_dependencies` and maybe also to get the gradients flow? I guess the scalar itself does not have any meaning. And I also guess to use it as a placeholder will not make so much sense. But I would have expected that it still works.

Maybe it's not possible to store values across several computation steps in a `TensorArray`? Is there any alternative? I basically needs exactly that. E.g. a `tf.FIFOQueue` would not give me random index access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.TensorArray` uses a per-run ("per-step") resource manager internally.
See `TensorArrayCreationOp` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/tensor_array_ops.cc). Per-run means, the resources will not be stored across `session.run()` calls.

If it would use the global resource manager, the demo code should work, as it then should keep the resources alive in the session. Unfortunately there is no way to change that behavior.

I tried to overload the class and implement one version which basically behaves just the same but uses the global resource manager. Unfortunately, `tensor_array.h` is not part of the official PIP package (reported [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10527)) thus this cannot be compiled with the PIP package.